# DTrace build in built-in variable stackdepth always return 0

Tags: ios, dtrace

I am recently using DTrace to analyze my iOS app。

Everything goes well except when I try to use the built-in variable stackDepth。

I read the document [here](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-variables.html#chp-variables-1) where shows the introduction of built-in variable stackDepth.

So I write some D code

```
    pid$target:::entry
{
    self->entry_times[probefunc] = timestamp;
}

pid$target:::return 
{
    printf ("-----------------------------------\n");
    this->delta_time = timestamp - self->entry_times[probefunc];
    printf ("%s\n", probefunc);
    printf ("stackDepth %d\n", stackdepth);
    printf ("%d---%d\n", this->delta_time, epid);

    ustack();
    printf ("-----------------------------------\n");
}
```

And run it with sudo dtrace -s temp.d -c ./simple.out。 unstack() function goes very well, but stackDepth always appears to 0。

I tried both on my iOS app and a simple C program.

So anybody knows what's going on? 
And how to get stack depth when the probe fires?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `ustackdepth` -- the user-land stack depth.

The `stackdepth` variable refers to the kernel thread stack depth; the `ustackdepth` variable refers to the user-land thread stack depth. When the traced program is executing in user-land, `stackdepth` will (should!) always be 0.

`ustackdepth` is calculated using the same logic as is used to walk the user-land stack as with `ustack()` (just as `stackdepth` and `stack()` use similar logic for the kernel stack).

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a bug in the Mac / iOS implementation of DTrace to me.

However, since you're already probing every function entry and return, you could just keep a new variable `self->depth` and do `++` in the `:::entry` probe and `--` in the `:::return` probe. This doesn't work *quite* right if you run it against optimized code, because any tail-call-optimized functions may look like they enter but never return. To solve that, you can turn off optimizations.

Also, because what you're doing looks a lot like this, I thought maybe you would be interested in the `-F` option:

> Coalesce trace output by identifying function entry and return.
>   Function entry probe reports are indented and their output is prefixed
>   with `->`. Function return probe reports are unindented and their output
>   is prefixed with `<-`.

The normal script to use with `-F` is something like:

```
pid$target::some_function:entry { self->trace = 1 }

pid$target:::entry /self->trace/ {}
pid$target:::return /self->trace/ {}

pid$target::some_function:return { self->trace = 0 }
```

Where `some_function` is the function whose execution you want to be printed. The output shows a textual call graph for that execution:

```
-> some_function
  -> another_function
    -> malloc
    <- malloc
  <- another_function
  -> yet_another_function
    -> strcmp
    <- strcmp
    -> malloc
    <- malloc
  <- yet_another_function
<- some_function
```

Comment: `stackdepth` appears to be working fine: try `dtrace -n sched:::off-cpu'{ @[stack(), stackdepth] = count(); }'`